# Android AlarmManager defaulting to 5 minutes when phone screen is off

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

So I am having an issue with AlarmManager. I am trying to run some code every 2 minutes, which works okay while the phone is awake, but not when the device goes to sleep - during sleep, the intervals are perfectly 5 minutes apart.

Since my desired interval is 2 minutes, this is roughly 250% off my target interval, which for my specific application is not acceptable.

I am aware of the changes in API 19, and have followed suggestions to re-schedule the alarm using setExact() within my BroadcastReceiver. Code is below:

The code used to trigger BroadcastReceiver:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,  0, intent, 0);

    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 3000, pendingIntent);
```

And this code is in my BroadcastReceiver which re-schedules the alarm:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "AlarmService Triggered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Service triggered");

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, this.getClass());
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, newIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 120000, mPendingIntent);
}
```

Does anyone have suggestions as to how I could fix this? It is very frustrating that AlarmManager is totally ignoring my wish to have an alarm fire at an exact time. Is there any alternative that will allow me to schedule code at 2 minute intervals like I want?

**DEVICE: Samsung Galaxy S6, OS 5.1.1**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Francesc suggested, it ended up being the Samsung device. Tried it on another phone, now it works flawlessly.

Let this be a lesson to you - don't buy Samsung, they do weird stuff, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Replace ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP with RTC_WAKEUP.

This is how I schedule alarms:

```
        mTargetTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout * 1000L;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mTargetTime, mPendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mTargetTime, mPendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mTargetTime, mPendingIntent);
        }
```

Comment: You are using 3000 for the alarm though: SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 3000. 2 minutes is 120000.

Comment: the initial 3000 ms delay is only to trigger the first Alarm, all Alarms are then rescheduled in the BroadcastReceiver with a 120000 ms delay. I will try your above block and see if it works for me.

Comment: the above block didn't help, still defaulting to 5 min intervals while the device is asleep